# AsyncTask status after cancel()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The documentation for AsyncTask's `cancel()` method states:

> Calling this method guarantees that `onPostExecute(Object)` is never invoked.

The documentation for `AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED` states:

> Indicates that `onPostExecute(Result)` has finished.

Does this mean that cancelled AsyncTasks have a status of `RUNNING`?  How can I tell a running task from a cancelled task, in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [the source code to `AsyncTask`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java), when the background work is done, either `onCancelled()` or `onPostExecute()` will be called. After that, the status is set to `FINISHED`. Prior to that, the task is presumably `RUNNING`.

You can also call `isCancelled()` to see if the task was cancelled, before it gets to the `FINISHED` state.

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29481442/3459910) is absolutely correct!

Just wanted to add the specific code snippet from [`AsyncTask`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) to prove his correctness:

```
private void finish(Result result) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        onCancelled(result);
    } else {
        onPostExecute(result);
    }
    mStatus = Status.FINISHED;
}
```